# How to setup a request.py for this machine learning models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, deployment, regression

I am following this [online tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-beginners-guide-to-training-and-deploying-machine-learning-models-using-python-48a313502e5a) and deploying a machine learning models using Python. I have done all the parts as instructed, including having created the model.py, and request.py files, and run those in Terminal.

But, I failed to create a request.py file to generate the prediction. My server.py is:

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import flask
import pickle

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl","rb"))

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    feature_array = request.get_json()['feature_array']

    #our model rates the wine based on the input array
    prediction = model.predict([feature_array]).tolist()

    #preparing a response object and storing the model's predictions
    response = {}
    response['predictions'] = prediction

    #sending our response object back as json
    return flask.jsonify(response)
```

And my request.py:

```
import requests
# URL
url = 'http://localhost:5000/request'

r = requests.post(url,json=[7.4,0.66,0,1.8,0.075,13,40,0.9978,3.51,0.56,9.4])
print(r.json())
```

Comment: this regression has 11 variables

Comment: you should show why you failure to request ，predict error or request error？

Comment: Thank you @Joyzaza, mine was a request error, sorry for my ambiguity .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import this in server.py file:

```
from flask import request
```

Add this at the end of your `server.py` file(used to run the server at port 5000 and `debug=True` to debug and solve the error, if we get any):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Updated `request.py` file(your code is missing `feature_array` key which you are referring in `server.py` file):

```
import requests, json
# URL
url = 'http://localhost:5000/predict'
r = requests.post(url, json={"feature_array":[7.4,0.66,0,1.8,0.075,13,40,0.9978,3.51,0.56,9.4]})
print(r.json())
```

Run `server.py` before running `request.py` file.

Comment: I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your server.py file is missing `from flask import request` as shown in line 2 in the tutorial?

Comment: that "from flask import request" is only an intro, the real one is at the box below.

Comment: i think my problem is at the [feature_array] part